# Removing Hidden Files in folder

Tags: linux, rm

I am having some trouble removing a particular folder on my harddrive.

I have tried the conventional approach of

```
rm -rf req      (where req is the filename)
```

however this failed.

running

```
ls -lart
```

revealed links to three additional folders. i.e. '.'(current dir) '..'(previous dir) and some random .fuse file. I tried deleting the .fuse file using rm -rf .fuse but doing `ls -lart` again showed this file not to be deleted.

Here is what I've tried...
[image]

Thanks in advance.

ps: What I have in the Videos directory I do not want to delete, only the req folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking carefully at those fuse_hidden files in the req directory, I realized that every time you try to delete those, a new one appears with a different file name but with different last character(probably gets incremented as the pattern shows). So there must be some process which is holding the handle and hence even if you delete it, its reborn.

Researching a bit more took me here : https://serverfault.com/questions/478558/how-to-delete-fuse-hidden-files

Run a quick "lsof" to check what's the culprit process, kill it and then try deleting the directory. Let us know if it helps.

Comment: For me, on a Raspberry Pi, lsof didn't show me anything, but the fuse file was obviously from the Plex server I am running. Thanks. This helped get it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of effort.

This did the trick:

```
find . -name ".*" -exec rm -rf {};
```

Hope this helps someone in the future aswell.

Comment: If you read this, don't blindly issue this command in your terminal, it will delete all files in the current directory.

Comment: I'd advise using the explicit folder name in order to guard against accidentally executing the command on the wrong folder.

Comment: I am getting `find: missing argument to `-exec'`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these commands and it did work to delete a particular hidden file and not all of them

ls -a

the above command will show all the files including the hidden files but the hidden files will be differentiated with a "."(dot) at the start in that whichever the file you would like to delete ,you can enter this command.

rm -rf .nameofthehiddenfile